# Error in inputting array and outputting it | Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new at Kotlin (and my English is terrible :).
I want to define the size of the array and elements in it by inputting it from the keyboard.

```
fun main() {
   val array_size = readLine()!!.toInt()
   val arr = IntArray(array_size)
   for (i in 0..array_size){
       arr[i] = readLine()!!.toInt()
   }
   
   for(i in 0..array_size){
       println(arr[i])
   }
}
```

[I got this message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRk9F.png
This is my first question in StackOverFlow tho, hope it is understandable for those who want to help.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message itself instead of pasting a screenshot: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1540818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is probably because the call to `readLine()` is returning `null` and then you're forcing that to non-null using `readLine()!!` which gives you the NPE.

In recent versions of Kotlin a new method was introduced: [readln()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html). It is recommended to use that instead of the old `readLine`. If and END OF FILE is found, the new `readln` method will throw a more descriptive exception, whereas `readLine` will return null which makes it more difficult to see where you went wrong.

You might get an end-of-file condition if the input is redirected from a file or other source. This often happens if you run your program in an IDE or an online compiler service. If you run your program from the command line, it will work, until you get to enter the last line. This is because `for(i in 0..array_size)` includes the value `array_size` which is 1 more than the last index, so you get an out-of-bounds exception.

Instead of using `0..(array_size - 1)`, it is recommended to use [arr.indices](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) which gives you the range of valid indices for the array.

Comment: Thank you! It's very cool that the community here answers so fast.

Answer (score 1):

`readLine()` is returning `null`, and so when you do `readLine!!...` you're getting a `NullPointerException`. Perhaps you want to use  [readln](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html) instead.

Comment: Appreciate  it!!